# App stuck on printing information from very first input

Tags: python, html, django

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from .forms import AddmemberForm, Lookupmember
from .models import Addmember

def add_member(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AddmemberForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'The member has been added.')
            return redirect('front-page')
    else:
        form = AddmemberForm()
    return render(request, 'members/add.html', {'form': form})

def list_member(request):
    context = Addmember.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'members/list_members.html', {'context': context})

def look_up_member(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Lookupmember(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            member_id = form.cleaned_data['member_id']
            if Addmember.objects.filter(id = member_id):
                for x in Addmember.objects.all():
                    if Addmember.objects.filter(id = member_id):
                        context = {
                            'name': x.name,
                            'email': x.email,
                            'address': x.address,
                            'city': x.city,
                            'state': x.state,
                            'zip_code': x.zip_code,
                            'phone_number': x.phone_number,
                        }
                        return render(request, 'members/about_members.html', context)
            else:
                messages.error(request, f'Error:  This member does not exist.')
                return redirect('look_up_member')
    else:
        form = Lookupmember()
        return render(request, 'members/look_up_member.html', {'form': form})
```

[The idea is to use a form that just takes one input, the member id.  This is supposed to be a lookup feature.  If no member exists with that ID, then an error appears.  If the member ID does exist, then it's supposed to redirect to a page with the member's information.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kx8FF.png)

When I tested this for the very first time, I typed "1" for the member ID.  This member does indeed exist, so I was redirected to a page with the members information.

The problem is for some reason, when I tested this a second time and typed "3", which is another member that exists, I still only get the information of member "1".  So basically, this worked only for the very first time I tested it.  Please explain away with any answers.  I have a hunch that the problem exists with the line "return render(request, 'members/about_members.html', context)", but I'm not really sure how to go about fixing this problem.

**Here is the HTML template if needed.**

```
{% extends "front_page/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}

    <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Email</th>
            <th scope="col">Address</th>
            <th scope="col">City</th>
            <th scope="col">State</th>
            <th scope="col">Zip Code</th>
            <th scope="col">Phone Number</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>{{ name }}</td>
            <td>{{ email }}</td>
            <td>{{ address }}</td>
            <td>{{ city }}</td>
            <td>{{ state }}</td>
            <td>{{ zip_code }}</td>
            <td>{{ phone_number }}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>

{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is with the following 3 lines:

```
if Addmember.objects.filter(id = member_id):
    for x in Addmember.objects.all():
         if Addmember.objects.filter(id = member_id):
```

The reason this doesn't work is because you start the for loop, the first x exists. You then just blanket check whether the list can be filtered.
If it can be filtered it doesn't mean that x is the same id as member_id.
You've already done the null check in the line above the for statement. My recommendation would be to change to the following:

```
if Addmember.objects.filter(id = member_id):
    x = Addmember.objects.filter(id = member_id)[0]
    context = {....
```

Alternatively for minimal changes (although inefficient as you are looping over all members and you don't need to) is to change to the following:

```
if Addmember.objects.filter(id = member_id):
    for x in Addmember.objects.all():
        if x.id == member_id:
            context = {...
```

Comment: @YomenTohmaz brilliant, glad I could help! As this was the solution to your problem would you consider marking it as the answer to your question by clicking the check mark? This would allow clear indication of the solution to anyone who may look at this thread in the future.